# Completed 401 Unauthorized on a password request form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We use Devise to authenticate. However, we use a simpler password recovery process. I've gone through numerous other similar posts whose issues are different.

Here is our form:

```
<%= form_tag send_new_password_users_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'username', nil %>
    <%= button_tag "Request New Password" %>
<% end %>
```

We get the following error message:

```
Started POST "/users/send_new_password" for ::1 at 
  2017-06-14 10:40:09 -0400
Processing by UsersController#send_new_password as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qqV6bE4vY...",
  "username"=>"Doe, John", "button"=>""}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting the user to be signed in before he can do `send_new_password` which (of course) is self-defeating.

So you need to bypass user authentication for that action.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except[:send_new_password]
```

Comment: We've all been there. :)